# Best way to increase post view count

Tags: django, rest, post

I need to implement a way to increase view count for my posts when the post is viewed on the client side. For now, I won't be handling removing duplicate views by refreshing.

If PATCH or PUT is sent to the server with the viewcount + 1 on client side, viewcount will be overridden if multiple users use my service.

Is creating a new endpoint only for increasing the view count the best practice?
If so, what would be the correct URI staying RESTful? (POST /post/count ?)

Comment: You can save `F('count')+1` to the database, then it is incremented in a transaction, so if the transaction can be atomically processed, it is incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Multiuser

Your endpoint should increment the viewcount in a `transaction`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/

This solves the issue of multiple Users using the page.

#### Restful

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194020/13168118)
and after looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194020/13168118)

I would say a `patch` request